# Event Loop For Subprocess Asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am writing an asyncio app using asyncio streams and peewee-async, when I tried to use:

```
async ...():
    await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(...)
```

And I got `NotImplementedError`

I tried to switch the event loop policy from `WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy` to `WindowsProactorEventPolicy` and it works, but then I get `NotImplementedError` from peewee-async.

So, how can I get over it?

Should I use the regular subprocess library with asyncio.to_thread or something?

-- If it wasn't clear -> I am on windows (11),
I am also using python 3.10

Comment: For anyone curious I just used the regular subprocess with to_thread right now. Honestly I believe the best answer is to switch to linux already so I could also enjoy other benefits like uvloop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.create_subprocess_shell) we see the note

> Subprocesses are available for Windows if a [ProactorEventLoop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.ProactorEventLoop) is used. See [Subprocess Support on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-platforms.html#asyncio-windows-subprocess) for details.

However, peewee-async uses asyncio’s default event loop policy `WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy`. To solve this issue, you can use the `asyncio.to_thread()` method to run the creation of the subprocess in a separate thread, allowing you to run blocking code without blocking the main loop. Here's an example implementation:

```
import asyncio

async def threaded_subprocess(cmd):
    p = await asyncio.to_thread(asyncio.create_subprocess_shell, cmd)
    return await p.wait()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I haven't checked it yet but I'll make sure of checking it in a few hours. I did solve it temporarily, by using `asyncio.to_thread` with the regular `subprocess` module. Are you sure that it's enough to just create the coroutine in a Proactor and then use it in a Selector? BTW your code makes it look like you are using the Proactor in both threads because it's the default for windows systems from python 3.8 and above.